# Simple Javascript .repeat

Tags: javascript

```
function makeid()
{
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var text = possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    return text;
}
makeid().repeat(1128)
```

My intention is for it to generate 1128 different characters, but as it functions right now it repeats the same single digit 1128 times. For example, it'll repeat B 1128 times instead of something like FJ4MC4F9S3V41Z5KD etc. How do I make this do that?

Comment: `.repeat()` copy the same string for 1128 times, so first letter gets copied. you're not calling that function 1128 times, if that's your intention

Comment: @itsgoingdown - it's actually the whole string gets repeated (.repeat is a string method) - in the case of the code above, that code returns a single character, hence why it is repeated 1128 times

Comment: @JaromandaX  yes, when it randomize that letter, it got copied. Didn't put up my comment well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeid( count )
{
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    var text = "";
    for(var x=0; x<count; x++ ) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
makeid(1128);
```

Comment: you may want to remove the `.repeat` at the end and put the 1128 as the argument for makeid :p